# how to sum a key values while matching another key value in php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array as below :

```
array
(
    0 => array("id" => 4, "price" => 1000), 
    1 => array("id" => 4, "price" => 500), 
    2 => array("id" => 5, "price" => 1000),
    3 => array("id" => 5, "price" => 1000),
    4 => array("id" => 4, "price" => 0),
    5 => array("id" => 5, "price" => 0)
)
```

And want resultant array like below :

```
array
(
    0 => array("id" => 4, "price" => 1500), 
    1 => array("id" => 5, "price" => 2000),
)
```

Where price is the sum of matching id, for eg. `id` = 4 price will be sum of (1000+500+0) in result array.

How to get resultant array in PHP?

Comment: With a loop? What have your tried?

Comment: Using a `foreach`-loop together with an `if`-statement?

Comment: I tried, but didn't get as expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$aggregated = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $price = $row['price'];

    if (!array_key_exists($id, $aggregated)) {
        $aggregated[$id] = [
           'id' => $id,
           'price' => $price,
        ];

        continue;
    }

    $aggregated[$id]['price'] += $price;
}

$result = array_values($aggregated);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/ctgD9

Answer (score 0):

With Simple `foreach`:

```
$arr = array
    (
    0 => array("id" => 4, "price" => 1000),
    1 => array("id" => 4, "price" => 500),
    2 => array("id" => 5, "price" => 1000),
    3 => array("id" => 5, "price" => 1000),
    4 => array("id" => 4, "price" => 0),
    5 => array("id" => 5, "price" => 0)
);

$sum = [];
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    extract($value);
    $sum[$id]['id'] = $id;
    if (array_key_exists($id, $sum)) {
        $sum[$id]['price'] = $price;
    } else {
        $sum[$id]['price'] += $price;
    }
}

print_r(array_values($sum));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/843883)

Answer (score -1):

> I edit the answer to add a line that will remove the error notice

Loop with foreach and use addition.

```
$arr = array
(
    0 => array("id" => 4, "price" => 1000), 
    1 => array("id" => 4, "price" => 500), 
    2 => array("id" => 5, "price" => 1000),
    3 => array("id" => 5, "price" => 1000),
    4 => array("id" => 4, "price" => 0),
    5 => array("id" => 5, "price" => 0)
);

$result = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    if(!isset($result[$val["id"]])) $result[$val["id"]] =0;
    $result[$val["id"]] += $val["price"];
}

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/2D5Ei

Comment: This is missing the identifiers, as asked for.

Comment: @localheinz Not really. The Key of $result is the ID.

Comment: No, the structure of the result doesn't match the desired structure. See above.

Comment: @localheinz It's a compacter array, I think we should let OP say if it's OK or not. So you can remove your downvote for now.

Comment: Alternatively, you could provide an answer that matches what the OP asked for, it's right in the body of the question. Sadly, your answer doesn't provide it.